# How to build executable jar from snowpark scala maven application and run from command line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, executable-jar

I am able to build a jar for spark applications and java applications, but the same is not working for the snowpark applications. I would like to know, How to build executable jar from snowpark scala application and run from command line. I m able to build jar but not able to execute form command line

Below is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: User Error Report: 
Java Stack Trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.company.snowpark.etl.HashProcessor
        at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.doDeserializeAndCloseInputStream(JavaUtils.scala:351)
        at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.deserialize(JavaUtils.scala:335)
        at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils.deserialize(JavaUtils.scala)
        at function_handler_0//SnowUDF.<init>(InlineCode.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.company.snowpark.etl.HashProcessor
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:745)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1965)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1814)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1639)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
        at function_handler_0//com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.JavaUtils$.doDeserializeAndCloseInputStream(JavaUtils.scala:348)
        ... 3 more
 in function SNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_KTVPWBIRM0FSHTU with handler SnowUDF.compute
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:127)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:67)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:442)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:345)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:487)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:198)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:135)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:781)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:677)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeQueryInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:238)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeQuery(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:117)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection.$anonfun$runQueryGetResult$1(ServerConnection.scala:358)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection.withValidConnection(ServerConnection.scala:810)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection.runQueryGetResult(ServerConnection.scala:353)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection.runQuery(ServerConnection.scala:336)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session.runQuery(Session.scala:781)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.createJavaUDF(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:735)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.$anonfun$registerUDF$5(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:117)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.retryAfterFixingClassPath(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:54)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.$anonfun$registerUDF$4(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:99)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.withUploadFailureCleanup(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:169)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler.registerUDF(UDXRegistrationHandler.scala:99)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:2368)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.functions$.registerUdf(functions.scala:2998)
        at com.snowflake.snowpark.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3110)
        at us.company.snowpark.etl.HashProcessor.<init>(HashProcessor.scala:228)
        at us.company.snowpark.app.SnowparkAppDriver$.main(SnowparkAppDriver.scala:24)
        at us.company.snowpark.app.SnowparkAppDriver.main(SnowparkAppDriver.scala)
```

Comment: What kind of errors you get when you run your jar from command line? You need to add more information as currently your question is very general one.

Comment: I have edited my question with error I am getting. I am able to run same application directly from IntelliJ but packages jar throws this error when I try with java -jar app.jar

Comment: Is us.company.snowpark.etl.HashProcessor class imported from another jar file? JNI (Java Native Interface) is not supported in a Java UDF. Snowflake prohibits loading libraries that contain native code (as opposed to Java bytecode) in UDFs.

Comment: us.company.snowpark.etl.HashProcessor  is present in the same jar file
But below line is not executing when running through jar, but it happens when I run directly in intelliJ---- [main] INFO com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDXRegistrationHandler - Adding /Users/user/folder/snowpark/target/classes to session dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have added below mentioned build in my pom and ran "mvn clean install". The executable fat jar is generated in the target folder in the project. More information about the maven jar plugin can be found at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/

```html
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-encoding</arg>
            <arg>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</arg>
          </args>
          <checkMultipleScalaVersions>false</checkMultipleScalaVersions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>us.company.mainClass</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>FAT</shadedClassifierName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the guide in the Snowpark Documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-scala.html#using-sbt-to-build-a-jar-file-with-dependencies